# django admin language changes randomly

Tags: django, internationalization, django-admin, django-i18n

I have recently started working with django internationalization. 
There is only one view and matching template for which I added translatable strings and made translations for 3 languages.

Now I notice that the django admin language changes in what seems to be random. It changes to more languages than the ones I translated to (english, french and german).

Anyone know what might have caused it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is cause by a weird behaviour of django's translation module.

`translation.activate()` changes the language for the **whole process**.

What I had to do is call `translation.deactivate()` after rendering the template.